# Getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'str' and 'bool' message when trying to run script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a python script where I'm trying to determine if .txt files in json format return positive or negative for containing certain statements. Some of the example statements are: **"elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content"**. After determining if each .txt file returns positive or negative, the script is supposed to write the result to a csv. There are about 100,000 .txt files I'm trying to process. I'm getting a `TypeError on line 22` of my code though. The full error message is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'str' and 'bool' message when trying to run script
```

I have included my code and sample .txt file in json format below.

**sample JSON format file**

```
{
    "detected_referrer_samples": [
        {
            "positives": 1,
            "sha256": "325f928105efb4c227be1a83fb3d0634ec5903bdfce2c3580ad113fc0f15373c",
            "total": 52
        },
        {
            "positives": 20,
            "sha256": "48d85943ea9cdd1e480d73556e94d8438c1b2a8a30238dff2c52dd7f5c047435",
            "total": 53
        }
    ],
    "detected_urls": [],
    "domain_siblings": [],
    "resolutions": [],
    "response_code": 1,
    "verbose_msg": "Domain found in dataset",
    "whois": null
}
```

**Full Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/virustotal_reporter.py", line 47, in <module>
    vt_result_check(path)
  File "C:/virustotal_reporter.py", line 22, in vt_result_check
    vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'str' and 'bool'
```

**Code**

```
import os
import json
import csv

path="C:/Users/bwerner/Documents/output/"


def vt_result_check(path):
    vt_result = False
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

        l = ()

        # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
        # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
        # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
        # Look for any positive detected URLs
        sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                        'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
        vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
                                                 for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))

        # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Dr.Web category') == "known infection source"

        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
        threats = ("elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content")
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats

        vt_result = str(vt_result)
        print(vt_result)
#        with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
#            outfile.write(vt_result)
#        print(vt_result_check(path))

        #f.writerow(vt_result_check(path))

#        l.append(vt_result)

    return vt_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vt_result_check(path)
#    for i in range(vt_result_check(path)):
```

Comment: Could you include the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: @glibdud Thanks you for your comment! I just added the full Traceback. I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: You do `vt_result = str(vt_result)` at the end of the loop, so when the next loop starts `vt_result` is a string.  I suspect you may want to move the `vt_result = False` line inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You convert `vt_result` to a string:

```
vt_result = str(vt_result)
```

This isn't a problem during the first iteration of the inner loop, but in the second one the value isn't reset and you try to do a `|=` on a string ("True" or "False") and a boolean, which fails.

You can fix this problem by moving the

```
vt_result = False
```

below

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
```

In case this isn't doable because you need to continue using the value from previous iterations, just delete the conversion line: `print` prints a boolean just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That now gets it working. I'm trying to now write the results to a csv file and I'm getting a new error. Here is the code I'm using to write to the csv:         with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write('%s, %s, \n', (filename), (vt_result), (i+1))

I'm getting a new TypeError message: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Well, you didn't use any string formatting. Try `outfile.write('%s, %s, %s\n' % ( (filename), (vt_result), (i+1)))`, or even better, `outfile.write(f'{filename}, {vt_result}, {i+1}\n')`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried that and I'm getting an error saying: i is not defined. Would I define it in my for loop?

Comment: @bedford Please avoid asking follow-up questions that are unrelated to the original issue. If you encounter a new issue after solving the initial one, that would be best handled in a new question (after trying to solve it yourself, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that on the given line, the values on either side of the `|=` operator are of incompatible types for that operation; one is a `str`, the other a `bool`. The expression after the `|=` should always evaluate to the `bool`, so you need to find where `vt_result` becomes a `str`. And you explicitly make it so a little farther down:

```
vt_result = str(vt_result)
```

So the next time through the `for` loop after that, when you go to run the `vt_result |= ...` line a second time, you get the error.